# Modifying a draft without downloading attachments

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have a draft saved on my Gmail account, containing an attachment. At a later stage, I realise that I have to add some text to the mail, via the Gmail API. At an even later stage, I decide to send the draft. From what I've found, the only way to do this is to:

1. Download the draft and decode it.
2. Edit the message body to your liking.
3. Encode it and save the draft.
4. Send the draft.

This is all well and good, until you have a big attachment in your draft. Is there another way than doing the steps outlined above with the [Users.draft: update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update), so that you don't have to download the attachments when you just want to alter the message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a simpler alternative at the moment. I'm not sure what API changes would be needed to support that use case, but you can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Gmail) and we can talk to the team about it.