# GMail API: adding attachment to existing draft

Tags: gmail-api

Does the GMail REST API actually permit adding an attachment to an *existing* draft? The Users.drafts update endpoint seems to replace the entire draft's content with all its parts, when I really only want to add another part/attachment.

While I could theoretically fetch the entire draft and write it back, I am concerned about the possible race condition when that very draft is simultaneously being edited in the GMail user interface.

Comment: We cant help unless we can see what you are doing can you please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to edit an existing draft (changing text content, add an attachment, etc.) is to [**get the draft, edit it, and do a modify call**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318329/modifying-a-draft-without-downloading-attachments).