# Gmail API - Update draft message keeping attachments

Tags: php, gmail-api

**Scenario**:

I am using **Gmail API** via **PHP**.

**Purpose**:

I want to edit the HTML part of the message.

Precisely, I want to add a tracking image in the message, keeping the attached files.

**What am I doing?**:

This:

```
//UPDATE
$opt_param = array();
$d = new Google_Service_Gmail_Draft();
$d->setMessage($msg);
try {
$plom = $service->users_drafts->update('me', $draftito, $d, $opt_param);
echo 'Draft with ID: ' . $draftito . ' updated successfully.<hr><hr>';
var_dump($plom);
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//SEND
$de = new Google_Service_Gmail_Draft();
$de->setId($draftito);
$plom=$service->users_drafts->send('me', $de);
var_dump($plom);
```

Probably the key point here is **$msg**.

I set it up with *setRaw*() message:

```
$mime = ...
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
```

But I do not know how to handle the attached files here.

I know I am getting things mixed up, but the online docs for PHP are really obscure.

Is there any way to just edit the HTML version of the message without touching all the multipart Message?

Comment: [**I asked this myself a while back**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318329/modifying-a-draft-without-downloading-attachments), and I think the answer hasn't changed. You probably have to download the attachments and make it into a multipart message, like you said.