# Update draft without regenerating "raw" field

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using Gmail SDK.
Calling drafts.update method.
Before that I'm using drafts.get method for retrieving a draft.

Question: Can I set draft Subject without regenerating "raw" field? Using PUT or PATCH method maybe?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I asked the [same question 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318329/modifying-a-draft-without-downloading-attachments), and I don't think there has been an update to the API to only update certain parts of a draft.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318329/modifying-a-draft-without-downloading-attachments